# Can't open .txt file with php Mac (Xampp)

Tags: php, macos, fopen

Here is the error message that my code is giving me:

Warning: fopen(users.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/assignment3/form.php on line 79
Unable to open file.

Here is my code:

```
$file = fopen("users.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file.");
```

I've just started coding with mac so I don't know very much about it. thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

**Run this code to find correct folder easily**

```
<?php

$txt = 'users.txt';

echo '<br> your php file is here : ' . __FILE__;

echo '<br> your text file should exists in : ' . __DIR__ . '/' . $txt;

echo '<br> your text file '.( file_exists($txt)?'exists':'not exists' );

echo '<br> your text file is '.( is_readable($txt)?'readable':'not readable' );

echo '<br> your text file is '.( is_writable($txt)?'writable':'not writable' );

echo '<br> your dir is '.(
        is_writable(__DIR__)?
            'writable, then you can create new files':
            'not writable, then you can not create any files'
    );
```

### [Demo](https://phpize.online/?phpses=b41381733f55c50f2a548b39fa4f4e14&php_version=php8)